# Java set servlet request into jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have to load some values from servlet to jsp page

My "order_processing.jsp" JSP Page code is given below

```
<%@page import="test.abc.io.User_Objects"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Order Processing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="OrderProcessing" action="order_processing" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <table align="center">
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <img src="images/otn_logo.jpg"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstname" name="txtFirstname" value="${reqObj.firstname}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtLastname" name="txtLastname" value="${reqObj.lastname}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Communication Email :</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtCommunicationEmail" name="txtCommunicationEmail" value="${reqObj.commEmail}" />
                <label style="color: red;">*</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My User_Objects code

```
public class User_Objects {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String commEmail;
}
```

My "OrderProcessing" code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class OrderProcessing extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            User_Objects fillObj = new User_Objects();
            fillObj.firstname = "Test";
            fillObj.lastname = "User1";
            fillObj.commEmail = "tuser01@xyz.com";

            request.setAttribute("reqObj", fillObj);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/order_processing.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("into OrderProcessing java");
    }
}
```

My web.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>OrderProcessing</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>order_processing.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>order_processing</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.abc.io.OrderProcessing</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>order_processing</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/order_processing</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When i debug this project and click on Submit button its gives the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'firstname' not found on type test.abc.io.User_Objects
```

and I also want to do some task on "order_processing.jsp" page load.
but when i run this project, my order_processing.jsp page display successfully but on that case my `doGet` method of `OrderProcessing.java` did not call.

I am using JAVA with Eclipse Mars.

Answer (score 0):

The object "User_Objects" is no java bean:
firstname, lastName and commEMail are fields and not properties.
Try to add a getter / setter for firstName, lastName and commEMail

Comment: Thanks my first issue has been resolved. Please can you suggest me "I also want to do some task on "order_processing.jsp" page load. but when i run this project, my order_processing.jsp page display successfully but on that case my doGet method of OrderProcessing.java did not call?"

Comment: if you load the page, then a HTTP GET request is done (therefore doGet is called).
if you submit your form, then a HTTP Post request is done (therefore doPost  is called).
Is doGet never called, or just in the case that you submit your form?

Comment: doGet never called.

Comment: your url-pattern (web.xml) is "/order_processing". do you initiate your request like "http://{yourhost-and-port}/order_processing"? If not: try to do so or change the url-pattern to "/order_processing.jsp". Keep in mind that your form has to point to the same url (action="order_processing" / action="order_processing.jsp"), otherwise your doPost won't be called..

Comment: When i change my "url-pattern" into "/order_processing.jsp" my doGet is called but after that my jsp page is showing blank.

Comment: any real implementation within doGet? Try to forward the request to the jsp as you've done it within the doPost method.            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/order_processing.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);

Comment: Is your question answered, or is anything unclear? In the former case: please upvote and / or mark the question as resolved..